# Need Pivot filter data to change in another worksheet

Tags: excel

I am using Pivot filtered data in another Worksheet. While extracting the data stored in Pivot in another sheet I want to put Filter condition also .

At present I am facing the issue that even though I am changing the Pivot filter ; the data in another sheet (which is linked to pivot data) is not changing.

For E.g

`GETPIVOTDATA("Head Count",'R1'!$A$3,"Emp Level","Level 3","Location","OFFSHORE")`

is returing same value for different filter

ALso how can i preserve the result in another worksheet for one filter o/p so that once filter is changed the data entered remains intact for a definite condition .

For eg. if for above I want Vertical as the Filter condition.

Vertical    Banking ..........This is the filter....

```
           
Sum of Head Count                  Column Labels        
Row Labels                  OFFSHORE    ONSITE  Grand Total  

Level 2                             1   1        2  
Level 3                            28.7 28.7     57  
Level 4                            18   20       38  
Level 5                            18   4        22  
Level 6                            12   6        18  
Grand Total                        90   17       107
```

O/P in Other worksheet:

```
Resource Category   Level 1 Level 2 Level 3 Level 4 Level 5 Level 6  
Resources as per June       186     382     446     429     264
```

Can this be preserved once Vertical filter is changed....
I hope I am clear..

Comment: Is your workbook set to Automatic calculations?

Comment: I havent got this point ..can you explain

Comment: Go to File > Options > Formulas and you will see an option titled 'Workbook Calculation'. Is this set to Automatic?

Comment: Yes it is set to Automatic

Answer (score 0):

Your *GETPIVOTDATA* formula is static. You need to make it dynamic.
For example this formula:

`GETPIVOTDATA("Head Count",'R1'!$A$3,"Emp Level","Level 3","Location","OFFSHORE")`

will always retrieve *Level 3* and *OFFSHORE* data regardless what filter you choose.
To make it dynamic, reference the arguments to the cell that contains your filters.

**Example:** You can reference it to a cell that contains your currently selected filters

`GETPIVOTDATA("Head Count",'R1'!$A$3,"Emp Level",$B$1,"Location",$B$2)`

This is assuming *B1:B2* contains your currently filtered items.
When value on those cells change, the argument on your *GETPIVOTDATA* will also change and thus return the correct output. HTH.

Comment: I think I was nt clear...I have edited my question a little. I can use if condition here bt like =`if(A1="Banking",GETPIVOTDATA("Head Count",'R1'!$A$3,"Emp Level","Level 3","Location","OFFSHORE")'  bt issue is that the o/p of banking changes in another sheet if I choose another Vertical e.g Telecom.. Is there any way to fix the o/p of Pivot without removing formulae..